# Hacer una iteración de un subArray de un array con ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-repeat

Estoy intentando hacer una iteración de un subArray para mostrarlo en una lista con ng-repeat pero no me funciona, mi eventualidad es que el subArray puede ser una variable distinta ya que se llena dinámicamente, esa variable es del sessionStorage pero no sé como acceder a ella para que el ng-repeat me funcione.

```
<div ng-repeat = "item in videoCalls">
    <li ng-repeat="vCall in item[sessionStorage.workspace + '_VideoCall']" style="list-style: none;">
    <span>
       <i class="fa {{defaultClassVideoCall}}"></i> &nbsp; {{vCall.Subject}}
    </span>
    <br>
    <span>
       <i class="fa {{defaultClassUserCall}}"></i> &nbsp; {{vCall.NameUserVideoCall}}
    </span>
    <br>
    <span>
       <i class="fa {{defaultClassDate}}"></i> &nbsp; {{vCall.Date.replace("T"," ").split(".")[0]}}
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <center>
        <button ng-if="vCall.isSender == true" class="active-color mdl-button--primary" name='{{vCall.Id}}' ng-click="initCall(vCall);" title="{{vCall.Asunto}}">
              Unirse &nbsp; <i class="fa {{defaultClassCall}}"></i>
         </button>
    </center>
    <hr>
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Y el controller?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Gracias, pero ya pude dar solución de otra manera